# PyTorch Tensor must be real number, not NoneType

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm following the guide:

> Python + PyTorch + Pygame Reinforcement Learning – Train an AI to Play Snake(YouTube)

But instead of Snake I use 2048.
When running the agent.py I get the error:

```
  File "D:\VisualStudio\MachineLearning\2048\agent.py", line 102, in <module>
    train()
  File "D:\VisualStudio\MachineLearning\2048\agent.py", line 71, in train
    final_move = agent.get_action(state_old)
  File "D:\VisualStudio\MachineLearning\2048\agent.py", line 52, in get_action
    state0 = torch.tensor(state, dtype=torch.float)
TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

How can I solve this? I uploaded the code to GitHub(https://github.com/ADude0806/2048)  Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are returning nothing in agent.get_state method (and also probably not doing other things there you might want to do).